# Unable to run Python Kafka Producer and Consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

So I have written a simple kafka program which sends a message to the producer, But when I run it I get an error saying kafka failed to update metadata after 60.0 sec. It would be great if someone could point out what I am missing.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer

class Producer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        print 'In Producer Start'
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

        for _ in range(10):
            producer.send(b"test-topic", b"test")
            producer.send(b"test-topic", b"\xc2Hola, mundo!")

        producer.close()


class Consumer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest')
        consumer.subscribe(b"test-topic")

        for message in consumer:
            print message



def main():
    threads = [
        Producer(),
        Consumer()
    ]

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/148762/kafka-producer-fails-to-update-metadata.html

Comment: Does that topic exist? Is the broker running?

Comment: Can you include the error you get?